# SQL and C#: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = INFINITY; Initial Catalog = Stock; Integrated Security = True"); // making connection   

    SqlCommand cmd;
    int ud = 0;

    //ud variable used in Updating and Deleting Record  
    if (txtprocode.Text != "" && txtproname.Text != "" && txtprotype.Text != "" && txtbrand.Text != "" && txtquantity.Text != "" && txtmeasurements.Text != "" && txtprice.Text != "")
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product]([ProductCode],[ProductName],[ProductType],[Brand],[Quantity],[Measurements],[Price]) 
            VALUES(@ProductCode,@ProductName,@ProductType,@Brand,@Quantity,@Meter,@Price)");

        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", txtprocode.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", txtproname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductType", txtprotype.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", txtbrand.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtquantity.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Measurements", txtmeasurements.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtprice.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully");

        //Reading data
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["ProductCode"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["ProductName"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["ProductType"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["Brand"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["Quantity"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["Measurements"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["Price"].ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please provide details!");
    }
}
```

`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` - this statement gets highlighted and error is shown:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Can anyone assist me with this? or tell me what changes to makes ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Specify the connection using the `SqlCommand` constructor overload: `cmd = new SqlCommand(@"your query", con);`

Comment: You can use it more creative than that ;) Please look into my answer

Comment: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use:

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["<ConnectionString located in web.config file or Create it in web.config file>"].connectionString;
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    con.Open();
    query = "INSERT INTO Product(ProductCode, ProductName, ProductType, Brand, Quantity, Measurements, Price)
 VALUES(@ProductCode,@ProductName,@ProductType,@Brand,@Quantity,@Meter,@Price)";

    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con))
{
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", txtprocode.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", txtproname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductType", txtprotype.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", txtbrand.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtquantity.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Meter", txtmeasurements.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtprice.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
}
}
```

By the way you error was in @Meter and @Measurements
In SQL query you write it @Meter and in

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Measurements");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `Connection` property of the `SqlCommand` object - or pass it as an argument to the `SqlCommand` constructor.

Also: please use the `using (...) { ... }` blocks - as illustrated here: [SqlCommand](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand).

Comment: also, it is a common practice to include try {} funally {} block to terminate connection at server ASAP

Comment: @ArturMustafin isn't the `using` doing that already?

Answer (score 2):

You're creating the `SqlConnection` and the `SqlCommand` - but you're never **connecting** the two....

The command needs a connection - I'd recommend setting it when creating the command:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Your SQL query here", con);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set the `SqlCommand` Connection property.

You can do `cmd.Connection = con;`

or

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product]([ProductCode],[ProductName],[ProductType],[Brand],[Quantity],[Measurements],[Price]) 
            VALUES(@ProductCode,@ProductName,@ProductType,@Brand,@Quantity,@Meter,@Price)", con);
```

Comment: yes it i did it ! but now some different issue is popping up

Answer (score 1):

Correct template is (Microsoft [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2)):

```cs
private static void ExecuteNonQueryParameters(string connectionString, string queryString, Action<SqlCommmand> sqlCommandAction)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            sqlCommandAction();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
    ...
    ExecuteNonQueryParameters(@"INSERT INTO 
        [dbo].[Product](
        [ProductCode],
        [ProductName],
        [ProductType],
        [Brand],
        [Quantity],
        [Measurements],
        [Price]) 
        VALUES(@ProductCode,@ProductName,@ProductType,@Brand,@Quantity,@Meter,@Price)", 
        cmd=>{
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", txtprocode.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", txtproname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductType", txtprotype.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", txtbrand.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtquantity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Measurements", txtmeasurements.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtprice.Text);
    });
    ...
```

Comment: I doubt this is from MS docs as it would not even compile.